# How to Superimpose on Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I want to draw a triangle with two points inside using matplotlib. Here is the code I'm using:

```
plt.figure()
triangleEdges = np.array([[0,0],[1,0],[0.5,0.5*np.sqrt(3)]])
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
t1 = plt.Polygon(triangleEdges, facecolor="none", 
              edgecolor='black', linewidth=2)
t1.set_facecolor('xkcd:salmon')
plt.gca().add_patch(t1)

drawSoftmaxPoint('blue',100,np.array([0.2,0.1,0.7]) )
drawSoftmaxPoint('red',100,np.array([0.5,0.1,0.7]))



plt.show()
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfXq1.png)

According to the code, there should be two points inside the triangle, but it looks like the background is covering them. How can I make them visible?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], else one cannot help. Specifically it's totally unclear what `drawSoftmaxPoint` is.

Answer (score 0):

you could use alpha and z-order in your polygon to make it happen (from the doc of matplotlib).  just try to set the alpha value between 0 and 1 to check if you can see your points.  and then maybe use z-order on your different elements to make sure the fill of the polygon is deepest (most behind). example of zorder:
https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html